# Excessive road noise in Toyota Corolla

Tags: toyota, noise

In my 2007 Toyota Corolla, I am getting very loud road noise when driving, unless my wheels are turned left. This is happening on the studded Winter tires (louder, obviously), and my Summer tires, both on their own rims. If I turn the steering wheel just a little to the left, the noise goes away, and the car is quiet again. The noise seems to be coming from the front of the vehicle, and the vehicle doesn't seem to rumble when I hear the noise.

Where can I start looking to diagnose where the noise is coming from and fix it?

Comment: I'm thinking the issue may stem with wheel bearings on one or both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a very loud, low rumbling noise means that your wheel bearings are going bad. I'd be willing to bet that depending on how the sound sounds, it is your wheel bearing.
They are not typically very expensive to fix, but you will most likely need to take it to a shop, because you will need a bearing puller to complete the replacement.